# Why is my custom component not rendering in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a component called OrderGuideSelect and I am trying to render it in another area of our app.  The problem is the OrderGuideSelect component is not rendering.  When I set up breakpoints I am able to hit inside of the renderOrderGuideOptions function but it never makes it into the OrderGuideSelect.js file.  I also tried putting 'export default' in front of the class declaration instead of the connection but it didn't make a difference.  Does anyone know how to get the OrderGuideSelect component rendering properly?

Here is where I call the function that renders the OrderGuideSelect component:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.renderOrderGuideOptions()}>
    <MBIcon name="ico-24-filter" size={30} style={styles.filterIcon}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And here is the rendering function:

```
renderOrderGuideOptions = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <OrderGuideSelect />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Here is the OrderGuideSelect.js file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchOrderGuides} from '../../actions/AppActions';
import {orderGuideSelected} from '../../actions/ProductAction';
import Header from '../../components/Header/Header';
import {createIconSetFromIcoMoon} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import selection from '../../selection';
import OrderGuideOption from './OrderGuideOption';

const MBIcon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(selection);

class OrderGuideSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchOrderGuides());
    }

    selectOrderGuide = id => {
        this.props.dispatch(orderGuideSelected(id));
    }

    render() {
        const {isLoading, orderGuides} = this.props.orderGuide;
        return (
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                <Header />
                <View style={styles.iconLine}>
                    <MBIcon name='ico-24-filter' style={styles.filterIcon} />                    
                </View>

                {isLoading &&
                    <ActivityIndicator
                        style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
                        animating={true}
                        size='large'
                    />
                }

                {!isLoading &&
                    <View style={styles.optionList}>
                        <FlatList
                            style={styles.optionList}
                            data={orderGuides}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
                            renderItem={({item}) => <OrderGuideOption guideData={item} isSelected={item.id == this.props.selectedGuide.id} onSelected={this.selectOrderGuide} />}
                        />
                    </View>
                }                
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    const {products, orderGuide} = state;
    return {
        selectedGuide: products.selectedOrderGuide,
        orderGuide
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OrderGuideSelect);
```

Also, I may be importing of the OrderGuideSelect component should be correct:

[image]

Comment: I don't know React Native but with onPress where is your component supposed to be rendered? It is just onPress, I think it is not different from onClick yes? You are invoking onPress with a handler function and it returns a component but where?

Comment: I don't have a place yet but I thought it should at least get into the constructor of the component file... no??

Comment: I don't think so. Your component is nowhere with this setup. Your function just returns some JSX but your app does not know where to render it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code calling `this.renderOrderGuideOptions` function on `onPress` event doesn't make sense, i.e. `this.renderOrderGuideOptions` returns the element but where to append it in DOM?

This should be achived using `state` in `React`. So you can set the state in `onPress` handler then use that state in render to show your `OrderGuideOptions` component.

So on `onPress` event bind the function handler:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showOrderGuideOptions}>
    <MBIcon name="ico-24-filter" size={30} style={styles.filterIcon}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Now this `showOrderGuideOptions` will set the state named `showOrderGuideFunction` to `true`.

```
showOrderGuideOptions(){
   this.setState({showOrderGuideFunction: true});
}
```

At last step use this `showOrderGuideFunction` state to render your component in the `render` function like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            {
                this.state.showOrderGuideFunction &&
                renderOrderGuideOptions()
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I've upvoted your answer since you keep the render function logic OP used. I changed this somehow but yours is more suitable I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want probably holding a state property in your component and show your OrderGuideOptions according to this state property.

```
state = { showOrderGuideOptions: false };

renderOrderGuideOptions = () =>
    this.setState( prevState => ( { showOrderGuideOptions: !prevState.showOrderGuideOptions }) );

render() {
    return (
        <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.renderOrderGuideOptions}>
            <MBIcon name="ico-24-filter" size={30} style={styles.filterIcon}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        { this.state.showOrderGuideOptions && <OrderGuideSelect /> }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to something similar to this

> class RenderOrderGuideSelectComponent extends Component { 
>    constructor(props) {
>      super(props);
>      this.state={
>        showOrderGuideSelect : false
>      };
>    }
>
> renderOrderGuideOptions = () => {
>      this.setState({showOrderGuideSelect: true});
>    }
>
> render() {
>      if(this.state.showOrderGuideSelect) {
>        return (
>          
>              
>          
>        );
>      } else {
>        return (
>           this.renderOrderGuideOptions()}>
>            
>          
>        );
>      }
>    }
>   }